# Llamada al método onDestroy() al cambiar de ventana en la misma app

Tags: java, android-studio, activity, android-manifest, onbackpressed

Estoy haciendo una actividad simple en android con diferentes pantallas para ver la funcionalidad de algunos sensores pero tengo un pequeño problema.

Una de las ventanas de la aplicación es un podómetro que cuenta los pasos sin problema.

En un inicio mi metodo onSensorChange era este

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor == sensorMov) {
        contadorPasos = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
        pasos.setText(String.valueOf(contadorPasos));
    }
}
```

pero aunque cerraba la aplicacion no se resetaban los pasos a 0 debido a:

```
sensorEvent.values[0]
```

Lo he cambiado y he utilizado SharedPreferences y un editor para poder manejar los datos de los pasos que lleva en caso de cambiar, el problema está en que siempre pasa por el método:

```
onDestroy()
```

y yo quiero que lo llame únicamente cuando se cierre la app y no cada vez que cambio de ventana entre las diferentes opciones que tengo.

He mirado en el AndroidManifest con un configChange pero no se si hay alguna etiqueta que sea cambiar de ventana, y también he probado utilizando un onBackPressed pero sigue llamando a onDestroy.

Alguien puede ayudar ?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> el problema está en que siempre pasa por el método `onDestroy()` y yo
> quiero que lo llame únicamente cuando se cierre la app y no cada vez
> que cambio de ventana entre las diferentes opciones que tengo.

el problema es que la memoria puede requerir finalizar alguna de las Actividades de tu aplicaciòn y en este caso se llamarìa `onDestroy()` de alguna de ellas.

Una opciòn para implementar una lògica que funcione cuando se cierra tu aplicaciòn es crear una clase que extienda de `Application`, esto lo realizarias dentro de [onActivityPreDestroyed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks#onActivityPreDestroyed(android.app.Activity)) o dentro de [onActivityStopped()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks#onActivityStopped(android.app.Activity)):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyApplicationContext extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApplicationContext";
    private  Context context;
    private static MyApplicationContext instance;
    public MyApplicationContext() {
        instance = this;
    }
    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();
        setupActivityListener();
    }


    private void setupActivityListener() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

             //* Implementar lògica aquì!

            }
            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPreDestroyed(Activity activity) {
       
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
             
    
            }
        });
    }

}
```

En tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` defines la clase dento del atributo `android:name` de la siguiente forma en application:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplicationContext"
    ...
    ...
    ...
```